# Any plans or designs in the works to improve the graphics of TGO when it's out of beta?

Tags: feature-request, design

Compared to the rest of the SE network of sites, TGO is quite bland visually. The design is spartan and plain and really just all-together not appealing. It's not ugly either, but it needs its own visual style like the other sites do. Are there any plans in the works to make this happen? I think a nice, looking site unique to  TGO would help get more interest here as well.

EDIT: Are there any plans or designs for once this site is out of beta? If so can we see what it might look like?

Answer (score 7):

All StackExchange sites in beta use a standard theme. Some details here: 
[The New Stack Exchange Beta Theme](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/). 
When it progresses out of beta, it will get its own design.

Sites remain in beta for at least 90 days, but may continue for much longer. There have been several previous questions about this, eg [How close is this SE to going out of beta?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-close-is-this-se-to-going-out-of-beta) and [Are we doing well enough?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/are-we-doing-well-enough)

Comment: Great answer! I knew that the beta sites used a standard design, but I didn't realize that a beta SE site couldn't have its own design until out of beta.

Answer (score 2):

Tents for the vote arrows.

Conceptual example:
[image]

Comment: I'd call that a tepee more than a tent. Either way I think that is a good concept. Another concept would be a mountain peak. I bet a good designer could create an icon that looked like a peak when right side up and a valley when upside down.

Comment: I like the tepee. here is what is could look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bPSa.png